# Using perf with GCC's "-p" option

Tags: c, linux, gcc, perf

I'm trying to profile some small C program using `perf`, like this:

```bash
$ perf record -F 10000 -g -- ./program
```

After that, I'm building the flamegraph:

```bash
$ perf script | stackcollapse-perf | flamegraph > flamegraph.svg
```

I tried to compile this program with and without `-p` compiler options (I'm using GCC on Linux x86_64, FWIW).

The problem is that flamegraph for the former case (e.g. with `gcc -p ...`) differs a lot from the latter. It looks more detailed as well. So my question is, whether `-p` option is really beneficial here? It's necessary for `prof`, but can `perf` take advantage of it too? Or this `mcount`-related code inserted by GCC simply distorts the profiling data, making it somewhat incorrect?

Answer (score 2):

`-p` generates output for `prof`, not `perf`. Different tooling. And no, I don't expect `-p` to be beneficial for `perf`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured it out by myself. Turned out there was a `-fomit-frame-pointer` compiler option in build scripts. `-p` apparently turns it off.

So instead of specifying `-p` I replaced `-fomit-frame-pointer` with `fno-omit-frame-pointer` and got a nicely detailed flame graph with no overhead because of `-p`.